# Vue and Typescript Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type

Tags: typescript, vuejs2

I have Vue component. In data() I declared variable to store selected row

```
data() {
    return {
      selectedTableElemRow: null,
```

and then in methods I try to assign selected row to this variable:

```
let tableElemRow = tableElementCell.parentElement;
if (tableElemRow != null) {
   if (!this.isTableRowElement(tableElemRow)) {
      tableElemRow = tableElemRow.parentElement;
   }
 }

 if (tableElemRow != null) {
    this.selectedTableElemRow = tableElemRow as HTMLTableRowElement;
 }
```

And I get error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS2322  (TS) Type 'HTMLTableRowElement' is not assignable to type '{ new (): HTMLTableRowElement; prototype: HTMLTableRowElement; }'.   ClientApp (tsconfig project)
```

Comment: Show your `data()` and at which line is that error message?

Comment: Error is in this line this.selectedTableElemRow = tableElemRow as HTMLTableRowElement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of the variable should be:

```
data() {
    return {
      selectedTableElemRow: null as any,
```

Comment: Adding "as HTMLElement" works for me! Btw my original error was:
Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'

myElem: myElemRef.current as HTMLElement